# How to solve grid and font warnings in Knitr?

Tags: r, warnings, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to generate som pdf-reports, which includes alot of diagrams in Swedish. The diagrams are plotted with a for-loop in a Rmarkdown document and then rendered with Knitr. The code from the markdown file is listed below:

```
for(i in 1:length(na.omit(unique(dataframe$Sections)))){ 
h2 <- 1-worn.time.qoute
h3 <- 1-readings.qoute
  worn.df <- data.frame(worn.time = c("Andel av tiden som användaren har burit enheten",
                                      "Andel av tiden då enheten inte har burits"), 
                      worn.time.qoute = c(worn.time.qoute, h2))
  worn.df2 <- data.frame(reading.time = c("Andelen godkända mätningar", 
                                          "Andelen saknade mätvärden"),
                       readings.qoute = c(readings.qoute, h3))

  worn.df <- mutate(worn.df, worn.time = ordered(worn.time,
                                               levels = c("Andel av tiden som användaren har burit enheten", 
                                                          "Andel av tiden då enheten inte har burits")))
  worn.df2 <- mutate(worn.df2, reading.time = ordered(reading.time,
                                                 levels = c("Andelen godkända mätningar", 
                                                            "Andelen saknade mätvärden")))


  grid.newpage()

  layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,2), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE))

  plot(ggplot(worn.df, aes(x = "", y = worn.time.qoute, fill = worn.time))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1)+coord_polar("y", start=0, direction = 1)+
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Användning", values = c(colour1, colour2))+theme_minimal()+labs(x="", y=""))


  plot(ggplot(worn.df2, aes(x = "", y = readings.qoute, fill = reading.time))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1)+coord_polar("y", start=0, direction = 1)+
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Användning", values = c(colour1, colour2))+theme_minimal()+labs(x="", y=""))

  cat('\r\n\r\n')
}
```

As can be seen above, I'm trying to generate some pie-charts (to use pie-charts is not my choise), in this case there are two different one reproduced a multitude of times (I'm aware that the iterating parts are not pasted above, on the other hand the for-loop does not seem to be the problem). The following warnings is generated when I try to generate these pie-charts, can be seen in the pictures below (the goal is pdf-format).

[image]

I don't get these warnings when I run the same code within the Rstudio-console.Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: A side note: `layout` is for base graphics. You `ggplot2` is built on `grid` graphics. You want to use `grid.layout` or you might look into the `gridExtra` package.

Comment: Could you boil your example down to the minimum (e.g. just one graphic where the error occurs). Make it as short as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.